# Custom Page Template and Category Exclusion

Tags: loop, customization, pagination, page-template

I have a blog ([bernsteinbear.com](http://bernsteinbear.com)) that uses the TwentyEleven theme. I'm trying to make a custom page template for the front page (a blog page) that gets all the posts except in the "Comic" category. I managed to do that, except the pagination got messed up... How could I exclude a category from the main blog, have it only on a separate page, and have pagination function correctly? I'm befuddled... Thank you!

Max

EDIT: I have full SSH access to my server, and can edit anything. No restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your template.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Exclude Comic Category
 */
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
       <div id="content" role="main">
                <?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'comic', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>


            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: hmm in what context is this? maybe some more code? :-/

Comment: Could I have a look at the query you are using to exclude your comics category?

Comment: I forgot what that was; I deleted it while trying new things (from Google... :-/) but it was something along the lines of `query_posts('cat' => '-81')` where `81` is the comics category

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if this sorts the pagination issue.

Comment: Alright, so if I update my homepage (the blog page) to a new page template, will this work as a standalone query? How do I limit the number of posts?

Comment: you would need to add `'posts_per_page' => '5'` to the query. Replace 5 with the number of posts you want to show.

Comment: How do I edit the homepage template? Or switch the template of the homepage?

Comment: I have this: `query_posts('cat' => '-81', 'paged' => get_query_var('page'), 'posts_per_page' => '5');` but I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW` on that line.

Comment: Why? PHP is irritating :-/

Comment: I still get the double arrow error; what's wrong? I copied the code verbatim...

Comment: You've been so helpful and PHP is so unhelpful :-/

Comment: Ok my bad... that line needs to have the query inside an array if using that syntax. Put the updated answer and try.

Comment: Alright so using that exact code I have this: http://bernsteinbear.com/test

Comment: Which is...not quite working :-/

Comment: Alright, I moved the query_posts before the loop. Hm is there any particular reason why sometimes the dates are out of place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1852/discussion-between-tekknolagi-and-joshua-abenazer)

Comment: unaccepting answer because pagination is broken

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work

Comment: `get_query_var('page')` is wrong in the code. It needs to be `get_query_var('paged')`

Comment: and that will solve the pagination issue?